# How to fix it? Error Task :expo:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Tags: reactjs, react-native, kotlin

if I try with react-native (npx react-native run-android) I have:
[image]
How to fix it??

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code or error messages. Please look over the [help], especially the "[ask]" article.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following lines in `android/build.gradle`

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks  this is solve but after I run I got this error execution failed for task ':app:checkDevDebugAarMetadata failed'

Comment: share your `android/build.gradle` code

Comment: buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        kotlinVersion = '1.6.10'
        kotlinCoroutinesVersion = '1.6.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0") 
    }
}

Comment: have you integrated the above code inside your `android/build.gradle` code?

Comment: add full code of  `android/build.gradle` in your question

Comment: Yes, I add this code in build file, I think sdk version problem...

Comment: the code you shared does not include def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249389/discussion-between-anjali-deshmukh-and-shivam).